# view gets updated only at the end of a loop

Tags: aurelia

I have a recursive function that pushes asynchronously data to an array serving as a view model. Its associated template displays the data using a repeater.

If I call the update function starting with an empty array, then the template shows the new data one by one, as they arrive. If I start with a non-empty array, then the initial data are shown immediately, as expected, but the new data get displayed only after the update function exits.

In despair I tried signals and/or the task queue to force the view to update but they were of no avail.

The update function looks something like this:

```
refresh = () => {
  dataService.fetch1().then((data1) => {
    return dataService.fetch2(data1);
  }).then((data2) => {
    return dataService.fetchOneByOne(0);
  }).then((result) => {
    LOGGER.info('congrats');
  }).catch((error) => {
    LOGGER.error('what a shame');
  }).finally(() => {
    LOGGER.info('done');
  });
};
```

The recursive update function looks like this:

```
function fetchOneByOne(counter) {
  return otherService.fetch1()
    .then((data1) => {
      modelService.addData(data1);
      counter++;
      if (counter < aLimit) {
        return fetchOneByOne(counter);
      }
    }, (error) => {
      if (error.message === 'i am recoverable') {
        LOGGER.warn(error.message);
        counter++;
        if ( counter < aLimit) {
          return fetchOneByOne(counter);
        }
      } else {
        LOGGER.error('we are doomed');
      }
    });
}
```

Finally, the template is bound to data of 'modelService'.

Do you have any idea under what circumstances this may happen? Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**EDIT**

Here is some additional info on modelService in case it proves relevant.

The data structure managed by modelService and referenced by all views looks like this:

```
let modelData = [{
  "id": "",
  "someData": [],
  "moreData": []
  }, {}, {}, ...
]
```

Therefore addData looks like this:

```
modelService.addData(data1) {
  modelData.find((item) => { return item.id === data1.id })['someData'].push(data1);
}
```

Individual view templates bind to their data by calling a function like this:

```
return modelData.find((item) => { return item.id === inputId; }).someData;
```

Maybe the fact that I need to call a function to get access to the data is related to my problems?

Comment: What does modelService look like, especially the `addData` function?

Comment: @AshleyGrant Thanks for your time. addData _pushes_ the new data to the array - in the debugger I see the new data being added immediately. It may be of interest that the overall data structure is a collection of complex objects containing other arrays, etc. The specific view template is bound to a portion of this. Would that play any role? What I don't understand is that after the update function exits, the template manages to update

Comment: It's hard to say without a minimal repro. Would you mind setting something up over on gist.run? Here's a starter gist you can use: https://gist.run/?id=90a0672b8a44e8982df7eb5d6f88cf79

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried to set something up using settimeout to mock my backend async services and the view updated normally...

Comment: @AshleyGrant OK, I think I identified the source of the problem and created a very simple repro: https://gist.run/?id=9764a2a3e40f72f798c7e373b0bf83d5. If myData.push('four') is inside settimeout, aurelia cannot 'see' the change, whereas if there is no settimeout, then aurelia will update. What can one do in such circumstances? Shouldn't signals help?

Comment: no, made a typo, failed to recreate the problem, will keep trying

Comment: What I would say at this point is that there's probably a bug in your app code since you're having trouble creating a simple repro.

Answer (score 0):

Just to not let this hanging, as @AshleyGrant guessed, there was a bug and it had nothing to do with Aurelia's binding which works very well despite the promises of promises of promises that one may attempt to scare it with.